# Trigonometric Integration ${\int_{0}^{2\pi}} \sin(2x)\cos(3x)\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

$${\int_{0}^{2\pi}} \sin(2x)\cos(3x)\, dx$$

I think you need to use a double angle formula but I am not sure how I am supposed to split the $3x$.

Comment: use product to sum

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

$$\sin(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a+b) + \sin(a-b)\right)$$

Comment: Why did someone down vote this. this is perfect

Comment: Don't know. I saw someone commenting the same thing but with a mistake, then deleting it, maybe he was angry.

Answer (score 9):

If you would like to avoid any of those trig formulas and know the complex definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ this is the easy to compute integral:
$$
\frac{1}{4i}\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{2i\theta}-e^{-2i\theta})(e^{3i\theta}+e^{-3i\theta})d\theta
$$
which you will find is zero by multiplying stuff and evaluating easy integrals by substitution.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity and minimal formulas supplied on midterms I tend to keep like with like, but thank you for the insight.

Comment: @goldenlinx no problem. If you go onto do Fourier analysis, the above technique will prove useful, so I thought I would offer it here to you and others. Cheers!

Comment: I'm only in first year of my mathematics degree so I will definetley be seeing that next year. Thanks again!

Comment: goldie, this ([Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry)) is actually the simplest and bestest single thing to remember.  i would commit more effort remembering this than a zillion weird trig identities.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I know that this formula is widely applied beyond first year, although with the formula sheets and the vast majority of problems I face have solutions in which trigonometry is the method we are taught to use to solve them. I think that beyond the current calculus course I am in it will prove much more worth my time to invest in it rather than now for the 2 or 3 trigonometric problems I will encounter. Regardless, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**Addition formula**
$$
 \sin a \cos b = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sin (a+b) + \sin ( a - b)\right)
\tag{1}
$$

---

**Recast integrand**

For the integrand, use the addition formula $(1)$ with $a=2x$ and $b=3x$ to find
$$
\sin (2 x) \cos (3 x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sin (5 x)-\sin (x)\right)
$$

---

**Transform integral**
$$
\int \sin (2 x) \cos (3 x) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int \sin (5 x)-\sin (x)\, dx = \frac{1}{2} \cos x - \frac{1}{10} \cos (5x)
$$

[image: integrand[1]]

Comment: I'm not sure why you got down voted before, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using substitution $t=x-\pi$ we get
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin 2t \cos(3t+\pi) \mathrm{d}t = - \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin 2t \cos 3t \mathrm{d}t.$$
So we are integrating and odd function and the interval is symmetric w.r.t. origin, therefore the integral is zero.

This is basically the same thing as saying that half of the [Fourier coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) of an even function are zero. (The even function here being $\cos 3t$.)